# any elegant binary search tree algorithm to work this out?

Tags: binary-search-tree

I was confronted with this problem, and would like to have a quick algorithm to work it out.

Given n Points in the 2D plane(none of them has an x value or y value equal to another), find out the number of all pairs of points which form a line with positive slope.(say (0,0) and (1,1), with a positive slope of 45 degrees )

Since the n is big( say 60000), so I need an elegant algorithm to keep it within 1 second.
I know it is easy to do it  with O(n^2), but it is simply to slow, which takes about 30 seconds. Is it possible to have an binary search tree to do it with nlogn complexity?

I appreciate anyone who would like to enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be able to do it mathematically..

Every set of 2 points there are (using permuations, I believe) will either be positive or negative and if they are random points, this means there will be average 50% positive and 50% negative.. So it would be the amount of pairs / 2.

Comment: That assumes a uniform distribution. If the points on the plane are grouped around a line with negative slope then the number will be much less than `countOfPairs / 2`, maybe even 0.

Comment: thanks for your instant reply, but it is indeed about programming, not math. I want to know the exact number of pairs given any n points instead of having an theoretically average number . Any algorithm suggestion that can be implemented?

Comment: Andrew, as far as I understand the question, the only time that is possible is when they are all perfectly aligned, in which case, if they were aligned in a positive line then all of them would create positive lines, so the average would still be countOfPairs/2.

Daniel, do we know the locations of those points? It wasn't specified so I assumed it was a hypothetical situation.

Comment: yes. All the points are specified in terms of its location. and you can edit the class "points", say overload operator < and the like, so that you can define how to insert into the BST.